# A tense problem in if-clause

Tags: tense

When we are not sure about the past situation, how do we use if-clause?

I'm not sure whether he came to London last night. If he did, today will be a perfect day.

I'm not sure whether he has come to London last night. If he has, today will be a perfect day.

Which one is correct?

Comment: They're both "syntactically valid" - but idiomatically, the second version is incredibly unlikely. You should avoid using the Perfect construction (***has come*** instead of ***came***) as a general principle in any context where you're not sure whether you need it or not.

Comment: last night, month, year, yesterday, two days ago, etc. **trigger the simple past**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your sentence slightly (while keeping the tense) to make it more idiomatic.

> A: I am not sure whether he arrived in London last night.
> B: If he has (arrived), today will be perfect.

Use of the present perfect perfectly fits the situation.

B is assuming that if he arrived last night, he will still be there - and presumably they can meet up.

It would also be possible to respond:

> B: If he did (arrive), today will be perfect.

using the auxiliary **did** with the base form of the verb **arrive.**

The difference is that conditional response **if he did arrive** does not assume that he is still there although this is still implied.